# How to apply Best Object Oriented Structure in Python

Tags: java, python-3.x, oop

Using python,having 3 classes and each class has 3 functions with same names and same arguments. The one difference is the attribute value is different but having same data type of all arguments in all functions. 
Example:

```
class A:
   method1(srt1)
   method2(srt2)
   method3(srt3)

class B:
   method1(srt1)
   method2(srt2)
   method3(srt3)

class C:
   method1(srt1)
   method2(srt2)
   method3(srt3)
```

The question is How to implement OOP concept on such a scenario? 
Suggestion: Can polymorphism be applied to such a scenario? Kindly add something so that I may apply best OOP structure.

Comment: Why not just use a single class that you can initialize with different values based on the argument to the constructor?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No I want to use polymorphism or inheritence like concepts.